# How do I define a function that returns my string in lower case?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to define a function that makes a string of text inputed into lowercase.

```
def lowercase(text:str):
     text.lower()
     return text
```

Once I put my test sentence into this function, it still prints out uppercase letters.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `return text.lower()` this method is not in-place, as with all string methods.

Answer (score 0):

`.lower()` returns a new value, therefor you need to store it in a variable or directly return this.

```
def lowercase(text:str):
     text = text.lower()
     return text
```

or

```
def lowercase(text:str):
     return text.lower()
```

Comment: Glad to no. If it helped please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the post

Answer (score 0):

```
def lowercase(text:str):
     return text.lower()
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def lower(text):
    lowered = text.lower()
    return lowered
```

You were returning `text` which was the input of the function, so the function returned the text which it received as input.